# iOS in-app purchase not working

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Basically I am trying to make the in-app purchase work, but with no luck. Here is my code for requesting a product purchase

```
- (void)requestProductData
{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers=[NSSetsetWithObject:productid];
     request5= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject: productIdentifiers]];
    request5.delegate = self;
    [request5 start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    myProducts = response.products;
    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }
    SKProduct *selectedProduct = [myProducts objectAtIndex:0];
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:selectedProduct];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

The strange thing is that both response.products and response.invalidProductId have 0 objects in them.I've already tried things like checking the Provisioning Profile, the appID, the bundle ID and so on. Also, almost 24 hours have passed since I added the in-app purchase in itunes connect. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you setup a test account at iTunes Connect? Are you logged into the store using this test account and not your real iTunes account?

Comment: I did create a test account and I signed out of my iTunes account, but as this link states, you don't need to log in the test account http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html

Comment: Good point. The test account would only be needed when doing an actual purchase, not just listing the products. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code for making the request. You have:

```
NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:productid];
request5 = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject: productIdentifiers]];
```

It should be:

```
NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:productid];
request5 = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: productIdentifiers];
```

You are creating a set with one object - another set with the product id.

Comment: Thank you a lot rmaddy. I just can't belive I lost a day with this mistake :)